# WSO2 AM and WSO2 BAM configuration issues on Windows

Tags: wso2

I am on Windows are trying to configure WSO2 BAM Dashboard to see API statics.

I am using WSO2 API Manager 1.5.0 (latest) for some time and it works well on port 9443.
Also I am able to start BAM 2.4.0 (latest) server.

But as soon as I go to my WSO2 AM Publisher interface and try to see All Statistics it says
- Refer our wiki to configure BAM correctly

This is what I see in my BAM logs -

```
 INFO {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask} -  Running script executor task for script am_stats_analyzer_253.

{org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.task.HiveScriptExecutorTask}
TID: [0] [BAM] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver} -  Exception: Cannot run program "C:\Program" (in directory "C:\wso2bam-2.4.0"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver}

TID: [0] [BAM] ERROR {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver} -  FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask {org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver}

TID: [0] [BAM] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl} -  Error while executing Hive script.

Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.hive.impl.HiveExecutorServiceImpl}

java.sql.SQLException: Query returned non-zero code: 9, cause: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask
```

I am not able to execute the Hive script on windows.
I have installed cygwin also - not sure what is going wrong.
I have followed all the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due the BAM cannot execute cywin commands. Please try to install Cywin into C drive and make sure no space in file path and add "C:\cygwin64\bin" to the windows PATH, also make sure BAM running user has rights to run cygwin commands ( in default nothing to do in windows, unless you may set some special permission ).

Comment: Gave full access to Cygwin folder to the user. But still I am facing the same issue. Do we need to install HIVE on windows etc. I am not sure if that is the case?

Comment: I noticed your cygwin is installed in "Program " folder, please cross check ,try installing in c:\cygwin  folder as mine. Also would like to suggest uninstall existing and install in C drive root folder. Also verify in PATH variable you have correct cygwin\bin path.

Comment: No - I have installed cygwin in C:\cygwin but looks like it is trying to run from c:/programfiles....

Answer (score 0):

Please makes sure you have appended value "C:\cygwin\bin" correctly to PATH variable "Environment variable configuration" section in Windows.

Reason for this scenario could be due to windows command line is looking for cygwin in a different path.